# Scrape link in web page with specific class php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

as the title suggests, I would like to retrieve links that have a specific class.
I have the code to connect to the pages and with the preg_match function I would like to take only the url that is in href = "url".

the structure of the link I would like to take and the one found in href = "", this link is in a table and can also have other attributes but not id, only the view class.

```
<a title="viwe" class="view" href="link">blablabla</a>
```

while I wrote this code

```
$curl = curl_init('http://prove/prove/pag/test.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/';
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
    echo $list[0];
else
    print "Not found";
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, the method you are trying to implement is not recommended, yet if you have to, this expression might be closer to what you have in mind, that I'm guessing:

```
<a\s.*?\sclass="\s*view\s*"[^>]*>.*?<\/a>
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J9WEz3/1/)

Comment: ah I understand, why?  And what would be the most suitable method?  use for example PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser